# How to convert an item that is retrieved from list to a string datatype?

Tags: development, javascript, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, office-365-developer

I am having problems with some strings i have the following code in javascript:

```
_result = currentQuizItem.get_fieldValues()["Audience"];
```

`"Audience"` is a column in my sharepoint list, and it has some names 
but I am not able to convert them to string

I am trying the following `_result.toString();` but it causes an error

how can i do that via javascript?

Comment: what is the type of `_result`? if it is an array of string, the use `_result.join(' ')`. print the value of `_result` in console using `console.dir(_result)` and update the question.

Comment: `var _result` it is a variable. in audience column i have a name value but i cannot convert it toString(); @AtishDipongkor any suggestion now

Comment: use `console.dir(_result)` and let me know what it prints

Comment: when i wrote `console.dir(_result)` nothing happend!

Comment: What is the type of your `Audience` column? Is it a multi-value user column? And if you didn't already know, when you do `console.dir` you need to open your browser's console (press F12) to see what it prints.

Comment: @Submits no its a column in Sharepoint list of type text

Comment: When you do `_result.toString();` what error message do you see in your browser's console?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32454/discussion-on-question-by-nderon-hyseni-how-to-convert-an-item-that-is-retrieved).

Comment: @Submits error says that toString() is unknown